# Implementing JaasLoginInterceptor in cxf for authentication

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have read the [link](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/security.html) that gives the information about how CXF will secure the services. I am new to cxf. I find difficult to implement the authentication using CXF. Can anyone tell how to implement the JAAS in CXF.Please explain about the phase, interceptor, realm etc.,

Comment: Hi @prashanthth did you find any solution for this